# Is there any way to select text in Google Chrome with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, selection

Is there any way to select text in Google Chrome with a keyboard shortcut?

The intention is to first select the word that the cursor points to, then the surrounding sentence, and etc.

For instance, something like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: when you say 'wrap', do you mean 'select'? _wrapping_ is breaking it onto the next line.

Comment: @Aganju I guess. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 2):

Normal Windows shortcuts will get you part of the way. Suppose you're in the middle of a word, as in your first screenshot.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> takes you to the beginning of the current word or moves back a word. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> will select until the next space, in effect selecting an entire word. (You can press that multiple times to keep selecting more words.) Of course, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> selects the entire text box contents.

Comment: Yes, I know of these methods. They are quite cumbersome. Thanks though, this could still be useful for those who are unfamiliar with it.

Comment: Two and three-key shortcuts are too cumbersome?